# django csrf token error(RequestContext didn't work)

Tags: django, django-csrf

I am using django 1.5.1, I have to use {% csrf_token %} on each POST to work.RequestContext did not work for me, here is my settings, view code and template code.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

def show_rates(request, doc_id, template_name='rate.html'):
    doc = get_object_or_404(Doctor, id=doc_id)
    hos = doc.hospital
    docts = hos.doctor_set.all()
    page_title = doc.name
    hos_name = hos.name
    if request.method == "POST":
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = AddToRateForm(postdata)
    else:
        form = AddToRateForm()
    return render(request, template_name, locals())

<form method="POST" action=".">
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span10">
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Rate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

RequestContext didn't work for me. I am confused.

Comment: What does your template look like? Did you place the token inside the <form> ? Also, using locals is cool but it takes all of the variables inside the view and exposes them to the template. This could prove to be less than optimal and thus you should put everything you want from your view into a dictionary and send to your template.

Comment: What do you mean didn't work?can u provide some of templates and say what did'nt work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` look's good.

This is the basic code you should use for `csrf`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
#@csrf_exempt says to make an exemption on csrf, but of course is not secure.
#@csrf_exempt
def show_rates(request, doc_id, template_name='rate.html'):
    ...
    #I suppose  that locals() returns a dict()
    return render(request, template_name, locals())


<form method="POST" action="">
    {# Don't forget the following line #}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span10">
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Rate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is there a way that I can avoid typing {% csrf_token %} each time i add a form post?

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't. You should put `{% csrf_token %}` in every form you use (!for internal URLs only!). If you have many forms you may think to put the forms in templates. For more information about `csrf_token` checkout the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it .

Comment: sorry about that, i used CsrfResponseMiddleware before, and i didn't not see the new csrf document introduced in Django1.4

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view definition to add this decorator:

```
@csrf_protect
def show_rates(request, doc_id, template_name='rate.html'):
```

And update your return response to not include the context_instance. No need for that really.

```
return render_to_response(template_name, locals())
```

Comment: sorry about that, i used CsrfResponseMiddleware before, and i didn't not see the new csrf document introduced in Django1.4